Nextjs app doesnt load neither dependencies or backend (springboot) while being dockerized and running on Nginx
I am trying to host a webapp with nginx and two docker containers with the images of the frontend and the backend and cloudpanel doesnt let me change nginx for something else.
PD: I don't have access to the main hosting panel credentials. It is also worth noting that both containers run smoothly, but the backend doesn't seem to work because of this problem
This is my config
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 quic;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 quic;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  http2 on;
  http3 off;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name DOMAIN;
  return 301 DOMAIN;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 quic;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 quic;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  http2 on;
  http3 off;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name DOMAIN;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  include /etc/nginx/global_settings;


   location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header alt-svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }
    
     location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /.next/static/ {
        root /;# Asegúrate de que esta ruta sea la correcta
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    
    location ~* \.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header alt-svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

Tried creating a local volume on the VPS and retrieving the credentials from there
